# Azure Pipeline Copy Secure file into build folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vite

I have a vite/svelte project which uses `.env` files for environment settings. I also have an Azure Pipeline which contains a secure file `.env.staging` this is on the .gitignore list of the associated repo. I'd like to download this secure file, copy it to my build directory, and then have its contents read when I run `vite build --mode staging` (well, `npm run build:staging` which includes vite build...)

When run locally from my machine `npm run build:staging` works as expected and reads the `.env.staging` file, however, it seems to get ignored when used in the pipeline, am I doing anything wrong?

Here's my YML:

```
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: "dotenvStaging"
    inputs:
      secureFile: '.env.staging'
    displayName: "Download .env.staging"

  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 14.15.4
    displayName: "Install Node.JS"

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      contents: "$(Agent.TempDirectory)/.env.staging"
      targetFolder: "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)"
    displayName: "Import .env.staging"

  - script: npm install
    displayName: "npm install"

  - script: npm run build:staging
    displayName: "npm run build:staging"

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: 'dist'
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      #replaceExistingArchive: true
      #verbose: # Optional
      #quiet: # Optional
    displayName: "Create archive"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
    displayName: "Publish archive"
```

I'm not sure if `CopyFiles@2` is doing what I expect or not as it just matches the `content` parameter to copy whatever files match, which could be 0 if I'm writing it wrong...

On another note, I also tried using `$(dotenvStaging.secureFilePath)` as the content parameter, but it doesn't seem to do anything either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naturally I figured it out as soon as I posted, I needed to update the CopyFiles part to specify sourceFolder, clearly it didn't like my absolute file path for content.

```
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: "$(Agent.TempDirectory)"
      contents: ".env.staging"
      targetFolder: "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)"
    displayName: "Import .env.staging"
```

Comment: sorry yes, I was waiting for the 2 day cool off period but then completely forgot!

Comment: I searched this for a couple of days. you have knocked it.